# Why is Google Maps Library for android so out of date?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm an Android platform newbie looking to port some of my Windows 
Phone 7 mapping apps over here. My WP7 apps use Bing Maps which has
current maps and POI data.

I went to the Android Developers Resources center where it shows how 
to develop an app using the Google Maps Library.  I did that and 
noticed that the maps were over 7 years old.

I posted that issue on the google groups forum and was told that Google had 
apparently given up on that library.  (Strange that they still feature 
it in their developer resources site.)

So, if they have given up on that library, is there another library 
they haven't given up on?  It seems odd that Google would give up on 
Google Maps (bad strategy).

What tools, libraries, etc. should an android developer use that wants 
to write compelling mapping applications that can show maps, POIs, directions that use current
maps and data?
Thanks 
Gary

Comment: How did you reach the idea that the maps were 7 years old?

Comment: Morrison Chang, My tract where I live here in Arizona was built 6 years ago.  It shows on Google Maps, Bing Maps but not on the Mapview for android phones which shows the area as natural land.  I was told on the other forum that this is because Google doesn't update it anymore.

Comment: Win Myo Htet, sorry, I can't make out what you are saying.

Comment: Win Myo Htet, I'm new to the forum.  There was another thread where I got a good answer.  thanks for the info.  I've been all over trying to get an answer to this google maps issue but unsuccessfull so far.  I can't understand why developers would tollerate maps so out of data.  This would never be tollerated over on the Windows side.  I can't imagine publishing an app with 7 year old maps and data.  Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original post here was from my experience writing the android "HelloGoogleMaps" application and running it in the emulator.  I navigated to my own location and saw that my whold track where I live was still natural land.  This made me think that the Google Maps were way out of date.  This was the general feeling of some other developers on another forum.  I went to online Google Maps on the web and my tract was there so this made me think it was the MapView software that was out of date.

Today, I went back to that HeloGoogleMaps application, and again navigated back to my tract and it was there!  I don't know what happened but the map is up-to-date now.

Sorry for the bogus post.
Gary

Answer (score 0):

Bing maps are not up to date ( I tested them and I can see a building that has over 3 years and still doesnt appear on bing maps). Alternatively to Google Maps, you could use Ovi Maps or your own custom maps.

Comment: The gist of my question is that it makes no sense the google would not provide good mapping services to the android platform.  I'm trying to get to the bottom of this issue and find out if good map data is available.